# Andengine 2d side-scroller like mario

Tags: andengine

I have a question there.
How i make character with gravity and available to walk properly i.e. what functions i need to use and how do i define fixtures? And do i need box2d physics world(i'm using tiled maps)?
So if you can, please tell me how to do 2d side scrolling platformer like mario with andengine.

My code what i'm trying to do :

```
    // Character:
    charactersprite = new Sprite(40, 0, this.character);
    charactersprite.setScaleX(0.65f);

    this.mScene.setOnSceneTouchListener( this);

    // PHYSICS
    final FixtureDef characterfictur = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0f,0.5f);


    this.mScene.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsWorld);

    final Body body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, charactersprite, BodyType.DynamicBody, characterfictur);

    this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(charactersprite, body, true, false));
    mScene.attachChild(charactersprite);

    createUnwalkableObjects(mTMXTiledMap);
    final PhysicsHandler physicsHandler = new PhysicsHandler(charactersprite);
    charactersprite.registerUpdateHandler(physicsHandler);


    // HUD
    HUD my = new HUD();
    Sprite forward = new Sprite( 50, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 170, forwardr){
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pEvent, float pX, float pY){
            if(!pEvent.isActionUp()){
                charactersprite.getTextureRegion().setFlippedHorizontal(false);

            body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(CHAR_MOVING_SPEED,body.getLinearVelocity().y)); // Don't look at there
            //body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(2,0), body.getPosition());

            }else{
                //body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0,0), body.getPosition());
                physicsHandler.setVelocity(0, 0);
                body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(0,body.getLinearVelocity().y)); // Don't look at there 
            }
            return false;

                       }
    };
```

And little forward :

```
private void createUnwalkableObjects(TMXTiledMap map){
    // Loop through the object groups

     for(final TMXObjectGroup group: map.getTMXObjectGroups()) {

             //if(group.getTMXObjectGroupProperties().containsTMXProperty("Zeme", "true")){
                     // This is our "wall" layer. Create the boxes from it

                     for(final TMXObject object : group.getTMXObjects()) {

                            final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(object.getX(), object.getY(),object.getWidth(), object.getHeight());
                            final FixtureDef boxFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0,1f);
                            PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, rect, BodyType.StaticBody, boxFixtureDef);
                            rect.setVisible(false);
                            mScene.attachChild(rect);
                     }
             //}
     }
```

}

So it didn't work properly. So what i'm doing wrong? Please help me.
Thank you very much!

Comment: You should probably ask this on the GameDev site (gamedev.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things you will need:

- BoundCamera (to make bounds for your map)
- chase entity (your player, so camera will follow your entity)
- FixtureDef with little elasticity (to prevent player stopping suddenly on the ground)
- create box bodies for your static objects (such as walls and so on)
- things like jump - simply use setLinearVelocity

Every 'feature' mentioned above, has its example - simply check and engine examples.

In this thread, I provided some more tips about how to code such game: [CLICK](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/mario-like-tutorial-t5588.html#p25259)